# Fastest and easiest way of downloading a few thousand (cca. 200k) consecutive blocks

Tags: blockchain, transaction-data, blockchain-data, blockchain-analysis

For a project, I need to download and analyze a few thousand (say around 200k) consecutive blocks with all the corresponding transactions data. I'm most interested in recent blocks. What would be the fastest and cheapest way to achieve this? Specifically, I would like not to spend on buying premium accesses to fancy blockchain analysis APIs, like [blockchair.com](https://www.blockchair.com) As far as I know, the Monero blockchain is not indexed in Google BigQuery database. Is there any other alternative I could use?

Comment: Why not simply download the daemon, run it (which will download the blockchain), then query it (using the [RPC API](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html))?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Does not the daemon start downloading from the genesis block? So, essentially, I would not need to download the whole blockchain, right?  Honestly, I'm mostly interested in recent blocks where we have the 11 ring size. Older transactions with smaller ring sizes are not that interesting for my project.

Comment: If you really don't want to download the whole blockchain you could use one of the many publicly available remote nodes. See https://moneroworld.com/ and https://monero.fail/?nettype=mainnet